# react native navigation constructor vs componentDidMount

Tags: react-native

why do I have "DEFAULT" in the title and "----Updated!!----" in the view when I set the value in the constructor? It works when I use componentDidMount but then of course it gets rendered twice. Does this mean that navigationOptions gets executed even before the constructor is executed?

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'DEFAULT'),
    };
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props.navigation.state.params = { otherParam:  "----Updated!!----" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // this.props.navigation.setParams({ otherParam: 'Updated!' })
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'DEFAULT2');
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
        <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why are you not using `setParams` in your constructor?

Comment: Sorry, I answered complete nonsense here.

Comment: Lol I had to edit my comment too

Comment: Thank you, this works. Not as expected because I have now the double rendering issues like with   componentDidMount.

Comment: You can avoid double render if you set the param before navigating to this screen.

Answer (score 0):

Having a static property/method in class, it does not simply mean that you want to execute/access that method/property before any instance is instantiated through the constructor.

Instead, it means that the property/method will be shared across all the instances of the class, that's why `static` attributes/methods are also called **class attributes/methods**, instead of instance attributes/methods.

One implication is that you can access those props without needing an instance of the class.

In your specific case, the react native navigation uses the `DetailsScreen.navigationOptions.title` for displaying the title of the screen.